# How to apply filters automatically based on search term?

Tags: search, google-search-appliance

Is it possible to apply filters/facets automatically based on search term?

For example, If there are two facets called "Category" and "Material" ,and If user searches for the term "plastic water bottles" where bottle is one of the category 
(Catergory=bottle) and plastic is one of the material facet(Material = Plastic).
I am looking for the option to enable/force search engine to filter based on category=bottle and material=plastic automatically when it has matching terms in the query.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.  It is possible to trigger oneboxes, keymatches and related queries based on keywords.